# Issues converting Python script to Node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

UPDATE: rewritten code but still not working

The new code below is still copying the functionality of the python script, however trying to simplify things (also using a different library https://npmjs.org/package/rpi-gpio)
The problem now is that is always get a similar read back, so it is obviously not using the feedback from the GPIO pins.

```
var gpio = require('rpi-gpio');

var pin   = 12,
    delay = 0.0005,
    startTime,
    endTime,
    duration,
    distance;

function on(){
    setTimeout(gpio.write(pin,1,off),delay);
}

function off(){
    setTimeout(gpio.write(pin,0,listen),delay);
}

function listen(){
    gpio.setup(pin, gpio.DIR_IN);
    startTime = Date.now();
    console.log('Start: ' + String(startTime));
    return;
}

gpio.on('change', function(channel, value) {
    endTime = Date.now();
    console.log('End: ' + String(endTime));
    duration = endTime - startTime;
    console.log('Duration: ' + String(duration));
    distance = ((duration / 100) * 3400) / 2;
    console.log(distance);
    return process.exit(0);
});
gpio.setup(pin, gpio.DIR_OUT, on);
```

---

ORIGINAL POST

I am trying to convert a working python script as a part of my RPi development project into node.js to avoid needing to use websockets.

This is the working python script:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import websocket

for x in range(0, 10):

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)

    #cleanup output 
    GPIO.output(12, 0)

    time.sleep(0.000002)

    #send signal
    GPIO.output(12, 1)

    time.sleep(0.000005)

    GPIO.output(12, 0)

    GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN)

    while GPIO.input(12)==0:
            starttime=time.time()

    while GPIO.input(12)==1:
            endtime=time.time()

    duration=endtime-starttime
    distance=duration*34000/2

    print str(x + 1) + ": " + str(distance)

    time.sleep(1)
```

The function of this script is to use an attached proximity sensor to measure distance.

My current (messy) rewrite for node.js (using https://github.com/rakeshpai/pi-gpio for the GPIO parts):

```
var gpio = require("pi-gpio");

function rightPingOn() {
gpio.write(12, 1, function(err){
    //if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Sent 1");
});         // Set pin 12 high
}

function rightPingOff() {
gpio.write(12, 0, function(err){
    //if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Sent 0");
});         // Set pin 12 low
}

function setRightListen() {
gpio.setDirection(12, "input");    // Open pin 16 for input 
}

function setRightOutput(){
gpio.setDirection(12, "output");  // Open pin 12 for output
}

function right_listen(){
gpio.read(12, function(err, value){
    //if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Listened");
    return value;
});
}

gpio.open(12);
setRightOutput();
rightPingOff();
setTimeout(rightPingOn, 0.5);
setTimeout(rightPingOff, 0.5);
setRightListen();

while (right_listen == 0){
var startTime = getTime();
}

while (right_listen == 1){
var endTime = getTime();
}

gpio.close(12);

var duration = endTime - startTime;
var distance = duration * 3400 / 2

console.log(distance);
```

All I currently have as an output of this script is:

```
NaN
Sent 0
Sent 1
Sent 0
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

oh man.  i think you're going to have a hard time with this.  I'm guessing the python GPIO interface is synchronous?

To start with, polling like this:

```
while (right_listen == 0){
   var startTime = getTime();
}

while (right_listen == 1){
   var endTime = getTime();
}
```

is likely to result in an infinite loop because the callbacks that are supposed to be changing the value of `right_listen` are never going to get a chance to run.  If the following section is supposed to occur in a set order:

```
gpio.open(12);
setRightOutput();
rightPingOff();
setTimeout(rightPingOn, 0.5);
setTimeout(rightPingOff, 0.5);
setRightListen();
```

and those calls really are asynchronous, you are going to have to chain them together explicitly.

Edit:  note this is only a guideline for how the code might end up looking.

(1) Notice I don't handle errors.
(2) That deep nesting is often called 'callback hell', modules like async can make the code much nicer
(3) There are likely small errors in here.

```
gpio.open(12, function(error) {
    gpio.setDirection(12, "output", function(error) {
        gpio.write(12, 0, function(error) {
            setTimeout( function() {
                var started = getTime();
                gpio.setDirection(12, "input", function(error, value) { 
                    console.log("received:", value, "after:", getTime()-started);
                })
            }, 500)
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: That's pretty much it! Looks like a lot of work to get rid of the python sockets...

Do you have any suggestions to make it work?
Or should i be looking at the best way of calling the python script from node.js?

Comment: @user3047558, this kind of application might actually be a good use case for Node.js if your code will be reacting to events generated from GPIO, and sending commands that may not get immediate responses.  If you have highly complex sequences of events I might look into using the async library to prevent deep nesting.